# Workbench Not Downloading All Results to CSV

Tags: workbench

I am using workbench.developerforce.com. I am querying the data and view as Bulk CSV. The results will show 2,000,000 records processed.  I select the download button (the blue arrow) and the .csv will be created.  When I look at the file in one of my analytics tools and only a portion of the records has actually downloaded (for example 1,200,000 of the 2,000,000 are in the file).

I then have to run multiple queries and piece them together.  Why is Workbench only downloading part of the results?  It's as if it there is a file size limit.

Comment: What tool are you using? Does the tool have a limit to how much data can be displayed?

Comment: Workbench does have some limitations.  Have you tried Data Loader?